# How to securely store password in local storage

Tags: javascript, encryption, cookies, offline-caching

I realize that there are other posts on Stack Overflow asking similar questions, and the answer is to NOT to store passwords in local storage, but I need to. If there is a better approach, please let me know.

I am building a password manager. I am trying to develop it to work mostly offline. The way it works is that the user stores their "vault" on my golang web server. The server is only ever accessed when the client or server needs to be updated. So: the user logs in, the vault is sent from the webserver to the client, each time a password entry (username, password, name, etc) is created, each aspect of the entry is encrypted using the user's "master password". Since I would like the webapp to be able to work offline, I need to store some version of this master password in local storage or as a cookie (preferably as a cookie). I would like it to work similarly to other password managers, so if anyone can provide some insight on how they approach this problem, please do.

What is the best way for me to store the master password locally? I would like my approach to be as secure as possible. If there is a different approach I can take, I would love to know. My main thing is that I need the webapp to be able to work offline.

Please note that I am not using node. If I can provide any additional information, please ask.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to store the master password locally? Wouldn't it be better to store the hash so you never have it on the client machine? I don't see how the question is Go-related.

Comment: @DaveNewton You're right. I don't need to store the password in plaintext. I only need to store some version of it on the client and use that same version to encrypt and decrypt the vault. How would you recommend me coming up with a secure version of the password to store locally, and how exactly would you recommend me storing it (local storage, cookie, jwt, etc)? And yes, you're right. I will edit the question accordingly in regard to your comment about it not being go-related. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to (as everyone is saying) NOT save data locally. That is a huge security issue. Other thing is that a Website can not be offline (unless its a PWA), so running the website offline is never gonna happen (Unless you create a PWA).

My Suggestion is that if you want to make it work offline you can create Chrome extension and use chrome.storage API for storing Encrypted password ( storing plain password is not recommended ). Even with web extension, it is not advisable to store password locally.

You can make it work offline if user is logged in and but not connected to internet anymore and browser is still running. Every time user open browser after closing it, you should (always) authenticate user again.

---

1). Since you are encrypting vault using plain master password, you can use any encryption/decryption method to encrypt master password ( which will be stored using api ) and to decrypt the stored encrypted password ( decryption is required as you will need plain master password for verification ).

Hashing algorithm is not a good option here, since hashing is one way encryption and depending on which algorithm you use you can have different hashes for same string.

2). Yes, you can check storage.local browser compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/local)

Comment: Great idea! I agree with your suggestion. I have two further questions. 1: you said I should encrypt the password and store it using the chrome.storage api. Do you mean I should simply hash the password and store it locally (like one would do in the authentication webapp). 2: would this approach work with a firefox extension? I would like to make both a firefox and a chrome extension. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I accepted your answer. I have one question: You said that I should encrypt the master password and store it using the api. How would you recommend generating a good encryption key for this?

Comment: Use can use ```Crypto.getRandomValues() or btoa(Crypto.getRandomValues())``` to generate random encryption key. You can R&D to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

Electron can help you to develop what you want. With Electron you can develop offline app's to any S.O.

And you only need to know about HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

Take a look at official [website](https://www.electronjs.org/)

Today a lot of apps are made using Electron, like VS Code, Slack and a bunch more, look at this link: [App in Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/apps)

And if you really want to test, do a simple app following this [Tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app).

To store your password locally you can do a encrypted key and concatenate the machine info to make part of the password.

For example:

You can get programmatically machine MAC Address +

And do a simple and less secure MD5 encryption, and you will get something like this: e99cde2308fb2ff5612f801c76b18f6c

In the world exists a lot of encryption manners.

Good luck.